# Transaction with `OP_RETURN` to a particular address

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, bitcoinj, op-return

How do I formulate a transaction with `OP_RETURN` to *a particular address* using the *bitcoinj* library?

```
SendRequest req;
Transaction transaction = new Transaction(Main.getNetWorkParameters());
transaction.addOutput(Coin.ZERO, ScriptBuilder.createOpReturnScript(
    "thanks for the coins".toString().getBytes()));

// add a receiving address for this transaction
req = SendRequest.forTx(transaction);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make an `OP_RETURN`-based output out to any specific address, since the `OP_RETURN` opcode marks an output as invalid (thus provably unspendable). In fact, an `OP_RETURN`-based output will not even enter the `UTXO`.

A zero amount is okay (and even encouraged) for `OP_RETURN`.  The `OP_RETURN` is paid for via the fee; putting a non-zero amount in `OP_RETURN` would just destroy bitcoins, so the miners do not profit from mining it.

However, you can create a transaction that has multiple output scripts: One can be a standard `P2PKH` of the form `OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <pubKeyHash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG` while the other can be an output with `OP_RETURN`. Just call `addOutput` twice, once with an address and the amount desired, and a second time with parameters for an OP_RETURN script (and a non-zero output value, I would presume).